# How to generate a index table from a CSV?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, database-design, database-indexes

I am recently working on better indexing concepts. as part of that, I am curious to know, How is index file(Table) created or how does MySQL generate the Indexes?

I am aware about creating the index in the database with:

```
Example : CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_list)
```

And based on the same concept, i want to do the Indexing for a CSV file that changes daily dynamically, I want to update the index file based on the new data that is added in the csv file. i.e Generating a index file from the CSV.

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL does not create indexes on files.  It creates indexes on tables.  The result is an internal database object, and should not be considered a "file". I don't understand your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes it creates on table, i want to use this same concept of database indexing on a CSV file, that is why i asked, how does mysql internally makes the index table?

Comment: This is a super broad question because how mysql works could span a book, or it could be a link to the mysql source code. The data structure it tends to use is a B-Tree so maybe start with that.

Comment: While it can be very informative to read about btrees (so do that), you might be overthinking it. Probably all you need is an ordered list and a binary search (or, vice versa, a bst structure, which is even similar to a btree), and recreate it daily. Most high level programming languages either have those included or need about 10 lines of code to implement. Databases use structures that are useful to how databases work, e.g. the ability to insert and delete stuff in the middle 100th times/s with the least amount of memory/disk block changes.

Comment: @Solarflare Could you please give me a example of this approach, i guess that will be more useful or some links or references that i should follow ?

Comment: @Evert I want to know, how does MySQL creates the index table, what is the algorithm or approach used ? I am unable to find it in the documentation , Any links , working example will be more helpful. Thanks.

Comment: MySQL uses [B+Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) (the source code is available but does *a lot* more than you need). As an index approach: a list/dictionary/array/... will do, sort it, search in it binary style. You didn't specify your language, but see e.g. [Array.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort) and [Array.BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch). Just add the values you want to index, sort, search. It's a two-liner. Other languages have similar options or need 10-ish lines to implement it.

Comment: Just to clarify: I don't want to say you won't get help on stackoverflow. Searching and sorting is part of every single book or lecture about algorithms, so if you ask the right question, you will find enough people that know that stuff. You are currently just asking the wrong question to the wrong people - to solve your problem, you (very likely) do not need to know in detail how MySQL indexes work or how they are implemented. So ask the <insert your language>-people how to solve <describe your actual problem>, (very) preferably adding some code and attempts trying to solve it yourself.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks, I am a python guy. But my question is how do i generate the index file from the CSV. My ultimate purpose is to be able to generate a index file from a large dataset(Let's say CSV for now) which will be changing daily so i am looking  for a approach that will update the index file based on that.

Comment: @Solarflare Hello, Thanks for your suggesition, I have put up the right question with more understanding. Please take a look, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56251770/how-to-generate-a-index-file-from-a-database
Also please give me a little piece of advice with a question:
can you tell me, while a index table is generated, how is it decided that one record of a index table will point to the address of a particular record ?
i.e how to store a pointer in database(Index table) that points to the address of a particular record(Main Table) ?